# What makes an element accessible? And why are tap gestures less accessible than UIButtons? How do I fix it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, accessibility, uiaccessibility

Brent Simmons [wrote in a blog post](http://inessential.com/2012/12/31/coders_in_the_hands_of_an_angry_god) that tap gesture recognizers, presumably on a `UIView`, are less accessible than `UIButton`s. I'm trying to learn my way around making my app accessible, and I was curious if anyone could clarify what makes that less accessible than a `UIButton`, and what makes an element "accessible" to begin with?

For more customizability I was planning to build a button comprised of a `UIView` and tap gesture recognizers with some subviews, but now I'm not so sure. Is it possible to make a `UIView` as accessible as a `UIButton`?

Answer (score 3):

Accessible in this context most likely refers to UI elements that can be used using Apple's accessibility features, such as VoiceOver (see example below).

For example, a visually impaired person will not be able to see your view or subviews, or buttons for that matter; but the accessibility software "VoiceOver" built into every iOS device will read to her/him the kind of object and its title, something like "Button: Continue" (if the button title is "Continue").

You can *see* that most likely the tap gesture recognizer will not be read by VoiceOver and thus be less "accessible".

Comment: I believe you can annotate every object for accessibility, so you could include instructions for the taps as well. But I would recommend to stick with standard UI elements.

Comment: You can give the custom element the "button" `accessibilityTrait` (a bit mask), which the button already has by default. This will read "button" after the accessibilityLabel. You should _not_ add the word "button" to your label.

Comment: Furthermore, VoiceOver can activate views masquerading as buttons that use gesture recognizers to detect single taps. VoiceOver will synthesize a tap at the view's 
`accessibilityActivationPoint`, a property that is customizable, but defaults to the center point.